# Kids sci-fi show episode where a group of kids order a pizza, which is then taken away and eaten by an invisible being

Tags: story-identification, tv

In one episode, a group of kids are experiencing supernatural things.

For example, they order a pizza which is taken away and eaten by an invisible being.  Another example is their friend named Ranger who is stuck in slow time.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to add any further details that you may recall. The more info you can give us, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you. In particular, it would be helpful to know in roughly which year you watched this, and when you think it might've been made.

Answer (score 8):

This is [Gortimer Gibbon's Life on Normal Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gortimer_Gibbon%27s_Life_on_Normal_Street), the scene you describe happens in the episode *[The Mystery of the Blood Moon Eclipse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4023312/)* (Episode 8 of Season 1), synopsis:

> To celebrate a rare astronomical event, Mel invites all her friends to a spooky sleepover, complete with ghost stories galore. But when it seems like an actual spirit has crashed the party, they all must hurry to solve the mystery before they become ghost stories themselves.

The character that gets stuck in slow time is Ranger Bowen, one of the three main characters in the show. He has trouble getting to events on time due to being easily distracted and forgetful. So on the advice of his friend Gortimer, he buys a watch with an alarm. It turns out that the watch is magical and once he attempts to set the alarm on the watch, he gets stuck in slow motion - time runs slower for him, effectively making him invisible to the other kids.

When he doesn't show up for the sleepover, his friends assume that he's late as usual. Ranger tries to communicate with his friends, causing weird things to happen. Later he gets hungry and eats the pizza they ordered.

> In the end, his friends find the watch and save him by destroying it.

The show is available through [Amazon Prime Video](https://www.primevideo.com/detail/0GHX28HI66KI3V6KFAL9ONJ8SJ/ref=atv_dp_share_cu_r).